# Divide number into defined stacks

Tags: c#, numbers, stack, divide, defined

So basically I want to split a number, for example: 862 in C#

into stacks of 100 (or below with remainder), so it would result in:

100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 , 100, 62

I know this is probably easily done, but I've searched and couldn't quite found a solution. I don't quite know what to search as well so that could possibly be the issue.

Cheers

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat(100,num/100).Concat(new[]{num%100}).Where(x=>x>0).ToArray()`

Answer (score 4):

This is simple division to get the number of 100 stacks and modulo to get the remainder.

```
int number = 862;
int stackSize = 100;

var results = Enumerable.Repeat(stackSize, number / stackSize);
if (number % stackSize > 0)
    results = results.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(number % stackSize, 1));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

outputs

> 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 62

Or as a one liner (credit to spendor)

```
var results = Enumerable.Repeat(stackSize, number / stackSize)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(number % stackSize, 1))
    .Where(‌​x => x > 0);
```

Comment: I rather liked my solution, but I must admit this is very nice.

Comment: Works brilliantly

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
static int[] DivideIntoStacks(int number, int stacksize)
{
    int num = number;
    List<int> stacks = new List<int>();
    while (num > 0)
    {
        if (num - stacksize >= 0)
        {
            stacks.Add(stacksize);
            num -= stacksize;
        }
        else
        {
            stacks.Add(num);
            break;
        }
    }
    return stacks.ToArray();
}
```

For your example, call the function with: `DivideIntoStacks(862, 100)`
This supplies you with an `int[]` with the desired values.

Answer (score 0):

while the number is greater than `stackSize`, add a `stackSize` to the stack, and subtract that from the number.  Once the number is less than `stackSize`, if there's a remainder, add that to the stack:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int stackSize = 100;
    int num = 862;

    var stacks = new List<int>();

    while (num > stackSize)
    {
        stacks.Add(stackSize);
        num -= stackSize;
    }

    if (num > 0)
    {
        stacks.Add(num);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's some spiffy LINQ one-liner to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int number = 862;
    int d = number  / 100;
    if(d == 0)
    {
        return (d).ToString();
    }

    int r = number % 100;

    string str = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("100", d));
    if(number % 100 > 0)
    str = str + ", " + r;

    return str;
```

Example works for non whole numbers. Just check if value is less then 100 or `d == 0`(You can check by any of these), so return zero. 
get the total number of hundreds in number and build a comma separated string.
At the end if value has some remainder with 100 append to the string with comma.